# Unable to handle this request

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, paypal-express

After being redirected to Paypal page, and click the Pay button i received this error.

[image: After i click the pay button in the paypal page.]

Comment: Please check your webserver error logs and add them to the question. It's probably a PHP error but without knowing the error message it's hard to give a useful answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you go through the payment approval process and about to return to the merchant site (www.houseofglamz.com)?

If so, What this meant was that the URL that you provided Paypal to return the payer to merchant site is having an internal server error 500. Perhaps checking on the PHP log, or Magento log files (system, debug, and exception log files in side /var/log/) may give you some more clues on what causing the return page to throw an error.

Comment: yes i think when i'm about to return to the merchant site. i will share the logs as soon as i have it.

Comment: but the payment didn't get through

Comment: I believe in Magento, the page that handles the return handler is responsible to run another finalization checks and post back to PayPal complete the transaction (in case a customer change shopping cart during the payment process). Since the return handler page threw the 500 error, it didn't get a chance to confirm the transaction with Paypal. Hence, the payment didn't get through.

Comment: when i refresh the error page

Comment: The requested quantity for "Sleeveless White Kids Dress" is not available.
Unable to initialize Express Checkout.

Comment: It's weird that the return handler wouldn't show this error gracefully on your store screen (ideally, it shouldn't even let you go past the shopping cart checkout). Anyway, the root cause of the issue is that the quantity of this particular product in inventory may not be enough to fulfill the quantity added to the shopping cart. Try login to the admin backend and increase the quantity of the product inventory and see if you still get this error.

Comment: Is there any extension to view the logs from the magento backend? Our developer is still not answering about the logs that i requested.

Comment: Try this https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/log-viewer-1.html

Comment: I empty the system and exception log and try again the order but there is no new error in the system and exception log.